# I want to deinstall and clean up after a partial Anaconda install

Tags: 64-bit, uninstall, 32-bit, python-2.7, anaconda

I tried to install a 64bit Anaconda on 32bit Ubuntu(thought I had 64bit) and it stopped in error,so before installing the correct version should I get rid of what is already installed to avoid conflict and keep memory clear, and if so how would I go about it? I am a big time Linux newbie by the way. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to remove the old install, check in two places:

1. In your home directory for the `anaconda` folder, delete that
2. Look in the `/home/$USER/.bashrc` for the `anaconda` `export` line and delete that.
3. If in `step 2` that line is absent then go ahead with the new install.

Now your good to go with the new install.

Answer (score 0):

if someone wants to delete partially installed anaconda installed through windows subsystem for linux. then try deleting the Anaconda folder present in C:\Users\\Appdata. serach there "Anaconda". and delete that. if it denies deleting by showing permission denied. then restart your system then delete Anaconda and all other related files and folder.

That's how i deleted my partially installed files.